# Swap two rows using sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table called `ticket` in which I want to swap two rows when user click up/down button from front end.

For this I added a auto-generated field called ticket_index. But I am not able to perform this action.

I wrote the following query

```
   UPDATE ticket as ticket1 
   JOIN ticket as ticket2 ON (ticket1.ticket_index = 1 AND ticket2.ticket_index = 4) 
   OR (ticket1.ticket_index = 4 AND ticket2.ticket_index = 1) 
   SET 
       ticket1.ticket_index = ticket2.ticket_index,
       ticket2.ticket_index = ticket1.ticket_index
```

Can anyone give me the right SQL query? Please let me know if extra information is needed for this. Thanks

Comment: This seems all wrong - why do you need to swap?? This is not how it's done in a proper SQL database.... I'd rather add a column called `Sequence` that defines in which order your rows appear (`SELECT (cols) FROM dbo.Ticket ORDER BY Sequence`) - with this, you'd only need to change the two values in your `Sequence` column and that's all you need...

Comment: Maybe `ticket_index` *is* the OP's `Sequence`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a case statement, e.g.:

```
update ticket
set ticket_index = case when ticket_index = :x then :y else :x end
where ticket_index in (:x, :y);
```

Comment: The OP doesn't mention anything like `ticket_id` in their post. I think the WHERE clause should be `WHERE ticket_index IN (4, 5)`. Otherwise it seems the way to go.

Comment: Hi dennis pls uplift your vote to this question I need this thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your ticket_index field is an identity (auto-incrementing integer) field, why in the world would you want to swap these indices?  Based on your question, it sounds like what you're really looking for is a way to manage sort order, which should really be independent of the index/primary key.  I know this doesn't answer your question, but my recommendation would be to add a separate column to control sort order.

Comment: I added a seprate column but instead of insert record in this I made this autoincrement so that each time i don't need to bother about fetching max value then adding +1 and so on..

Comment: "Identity" columns are not really meant for this.  Your best bet might be to mimic Identity behavior using an insert trigger.  I would also recommend not placing a unique constraint on the column so swapping can be done without any major issues.

Comment: Hi keith, pls uplift your vote to this question I need it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you just update the two rows?

```
UPDATE ticket SET ticket_index = 4 WHERE ticket_id = 18

UPDATE ticket SET ticket_index = 5 WHERE ticket_id = 301
```

Use a brief transaction to ensure you update both records.

Comment: Would this cause issues if he if enforcing uniqueness on `ticket_index`?

Comment: Yes it would... more schema information required for that one.

Comment: I solve this issue with following query UPDATE ticket SET ticket_index =
(CASE WHEN ticket_index=10 THEN 20
WHEN ticket_index=20 THEN 10 END) WHERE ticket_index IN (20, 10)  but problem here arising that ticket_index is an autoincrement column so each time i have to turn off that,is there any other solution ?

Comment: I think you should probably add a column called sort_order which is additional to the auto-incrementing id. That way you can leave the id well alone and just adjust the sort_order to change the order of things.

Comment: Hi Sohnee,uplift your vote to this question I need it thanks :)

Comment: @VishalPatwardhan hello - I'm not sure what you are after!

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you have an order column (e.g. ticket_order).

Observation: moving a ticket with ticket_order N down has the same effect as moving a ticket with ticket_order N+1 up, therefore you only need one routine to swap two elements (whether it is moving up or down).

In this case we create a "move down routine", which only needs one parameter: the order of the ticket you want to move down. Your final query, however, might need more arguments to uniquely identify the two tickets for which you want to swap the order. For example, you might need to add a ticket category or whatever.

The (one) query this routine needs is thus (where [order] is the order of the ticket you want to move down):

```
UPDATE tickets
SET ticket_order = 2 * [order] - ticket_order + 1
WHERE ticket_order IN ([order], [order]+1)
(and possibly additional arguments here to further identify the tickets)
```